# Why does df.apply(tuple) work but not df.apply(list)?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, apply

Here's a dataframe:

```
    A  B  C
0   6  2 -5
1   2  5  2
2  10  3  1
3  -5  2  8
4   3  6  2
```

I could retrieve a column which is basically a tuple of columns from the original `df` using `df.apply`:

```
out = df.apply(tuple, 1)
print(out)

0    (6, 2, -5)
1     (2, 5, 2)
2    (10, 3, 1)
3    (-5, 2, 8)
4     (3, 6, 2)
dtype: object
```

But if I want a list of values instead of a tuple of them, I can't do it, because it doesn't give me what I expect:

```
out = df.apply(list, 1)
print(out)

    A  B  C
0   6  2 -5
1   2  5  2
2  10  3  1
3  -5  2  8
4   3  6  2
```

Instead, I need to do:

```
out = pd.Series(df.values.tolist())
print(out)

0    [6, 2, -5]
1     [2, 5, 2]
2    [10, 3, 1]
3    [-5, 2, 8]
4     [3, 6, 2]
dtype: object
```

Why can't I use `df.apply(list, 1)` to get what I want?

---

**Appendix**

Timings of some possible workarounds:

```
df_test = pd.concat([df] * 10000, 0)

%timeit pd.Series(df.values.tolist()) # original workaround
10000 loops, best of 3: 161 µs per loop

%timeit df.apply(tuple, 1).apply(list, 1) # proposed by Alexander
1000 loops, best of 3: 615 µs per loop
```

Comment: Strange behaviour. `df.apply(tuple, 1).apply(list)` as workaround?

Comment: @Alexander Possible, but slow. :( Added some timings.

Comment: At the point where you have a DataFrame of list-objects, you've pretty much abandoned all hope of speed and efficiency anyways... Note, `.apply` is just a wrapper around a Python for-loop, so just use `iterrows` with a for-loop yourself and that will likely be *faster* than either `.apply` approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Statutory Warning I'm aware of... was just curious to know why pandas doesn't behave consistently with lists and tuples.

Comment: Probably because it is not really meant to work with either of them as items, and I am willing to bet that it special-cases lists of lists to work like arrays somewhere deep in the bowels of the handling in `pd.DataFrame.apply`, but doesn't do that with `tuple`s. But if you really care about a workaround for an `.apply` that isn't working, (that isn't using ufuncs to begin with), then a for-loop with `iterrows` or `iteritems` is the way to go...

Comment: soooo probably want to start looking somewhere [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L4329). Have fun!

Comment: @wim Nice! A little description in an answer and I can mark it accepted. Thanks for all the sleuthing.

Comment: Instead of taking @wim's word for it, I looked for myself... and yeah, wim is correct. (-:

Comment: But here's the thing.  Even if it didn't return that error, still not what you want.  `df.apply(tuple, 1)` is slow too.  I'd use this for it anyway `pd.Series([tuple(x) for x in df.values.tolist()])`.  That means `pd.Series(df.values.tolist())` is a better solution anyway.

Comment: Another workaround might be `pd.Series([[a,b,c] for a,b,c in zip(df_test.A,df_test.B,df_test.C)])` though it's still not as efficient as yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/36dadd70376c6033037af281a4669a360fc71cfa/pandas/core/frame.py#L4707-L4708).  With `func=tuple` it works, but using `func=list` raises an exception from within the compiled module `lib.reduce`:

```
ValueError: ('function does not reduce', 0)
```

As you can see, they catch the exception but don't bother to handle it.

Even without the too-broad except clause, **that's a bug in pandas**.  You might try to raise it on their tracker, but similar issues have been closed with some flavour of wont-fix or dupe.

[16321: weird behavior using apply() creating list based on current columns](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16321)

[15628: Dataframe.apply does not always return a Series when reduce=True](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15628)

That latter issue got closed, then reopened, and converted into a docs enhancement request some months ago, and now seems to be being used as a dumping ground for any related issues.

Presumably it's not a high priority because, as [piRSquared commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928415/why-does-df-applytuple-work-but-not-df-applylist#comment78816348_45928415) (and one of the pandas maintainers [commented the same](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16321#issuecomment-300572545)), you're better off with a list comprehension:

```
pd.Series([list(x) for x in df.itertuples(index=False)])
```

Typically `apply` would be using a [numpy ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html) or similar.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll look into these links.