# Pandas Merge row data with multiple values to Python list for a column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a data-frame that looks like

### DATA

```
*id*,             *name*,                      *URL*,                 *Type*  
    2,             birth_france_by_region,    http://abc. com,       T1 
    2,             birth_france_by_region,    http://pt. python,     T2 
    3,             long_lat,                  http://abc. com,       T3 
    3,             long_lat,                  http://pqur. com,      T1 
    4,             random_time_series,        http://sadsdc. com,    T2 
    4,             random_time_series,        http://sadcadf. com,   T3
    5,             birth_names,               http://google. com,    T1 
    5,             birth_names,               http://helloworld. com,T2 
    5,             birth_names,               http://hu. com,        T3
```

I want a this dataframe to merge the rows where id are equal and have a list of **Type** corresponding list of **URL** 
so final output should be like

```
*id*, *name*,             *URL*,                               *Type*  
2,birth_france_by_region,  [http://abc .com,http://pt.python], [T1,T2] 
3,long_lat,           [http://abc .com,http://pqur. com],       [T3,T1] 
4,random_time_series, [http://sadsdc. com,http://sadcadf .com,],[T2,T3] 
5,birth_names,        [http://google .com,http://helloworld. com,
                                       http://hu. com] ,   [T1,T2,T3]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby/66018377#66018377) question tackles the case of a dataframe of only two columns. Amongst the answers is a warning that the solutions similar to the one accepted here ( in their simplest form:`df.groupby['id'].agg(list)`) have a huge performance issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `tuple` and then convert to `list`:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','name']).agg(tuple).applymap(list).reset_index()

print (df)
   id                    name  \
0   2  birth_france_by_region   
1   3                long_lat   
2   4      random_time_series   
3   5             birth_names   

                                                 URL          Type  
0                 [http://abc.cm, http://pt.python]      [T1, T2]  
1                  [http://abc.cm, http://pqur.com]      [T3, T1]  
2            [http://sadsdc.com, http://sadcadf.com]      [T2, T3]  
3  [http://google.;com, http://helloworld.com, ht...  [T1, T2, T3]
```

Because in version 0.20.3 raise error:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','name']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

> ValueError: Function does not reduce

Comment: Sir it works only if I pass 'name' as groupby paramter when I passed id and name I got Function does not reduce error.

Comment: Now its perfect.

Comment: Yes, it looks like bug.

Comment: Now its upto you to raise an issue :)

Comment: @Bharathshetty & jezrael: The bug is closely related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928415/why-does-df-applytuple-work-but-not-df-applylist

Comment: @jezrael: I want the same thing..just need a specified column to be merged and not all?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Specify column after `groupby` like `df = df.groupby(['id','name'])['Type'].agg(lambda x: tuple(x)).applymap(list).reset_index()`

Comment: It works but I looses all the other columns, should I merge with the old one or their is a way in this solution to achieve this!!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - If aggregate, you need aggregation function for each column, else are lost.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the expected result for the "URL" column:

```
test.groupby(["id", "name"])['URL'].apply(list)

id  name                  
2   birth_france_by_region                 [http://abc. com, http://pt. python]
3   long_lat                                [http://abc. com, http://pqur. com]
4   random_time_series                [http://sadsdc. com, http://sadcadf. com]
5   birth_names               [http://google. com, http://helloworld. com, h...
```

However, I can't find a solution for both URL and Type columns.

I could propose to do it in 2 steps:

- `temp_table1 = test.groupby(["id", "name"])['URL'].apply(list)`
- `temp_table2 = test.groupby(["id", "name"])['Type'].apply(list)`
- Merge `temp_table1` & `temp_table2`

Comment: why would you propose two steps when it is already done in one. And I think you meant concat over axis 1 rather than merge.

Answer (score 0):

The completed solution for the two columns given above is:

```
    df_new.groupby(['matching_value']).agg({
        'entity_id':lambda x: x.tolist(),
        'fullname': lambda x: x.tolist()}
                                           )
```