# Python code to get upstream segment from downstream segment in GeoPandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to set up a stream network with a geodataframe that shows what each individual cell (polygon) is connected to, up and downstream.  The cell can have many upstream connections, but only 1 downstream connection.  The cells are ordered from highest elevation to lowest elevation.

The image shows an example of the what the stream cells could look like, with the dataframe that I have showing what each segment is connected to downstream.  What I'm unsure of is how to get the upstream connections because it's not a 1 to 1, but can be a 1 to 1 or a 1 to many connection.  Any help on how to accomplish this in python would be appreciated.[Image showing stream network, dataframe I have, dataframe I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIdAR.png)

If image link doesnt work, example stream polygon segments.

| _ | _ | _ |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 1 |
|  |  | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
|  |  | 6 |
|  |  | 7 |

Dataframe I have:

| segment | downstream segment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | - |

Dataframe I want:

| segment | downstream segment | upstream segment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | - |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | - |
| 4 | 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 | 2, 4 |
| 6 | 7 | 5 |
| 7 | - | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas Merge row data with multiple values to Python list for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275765/pandas-merge-row-data-with-multiple-values-to-python-list-for-a-column)

This didn't answer exactly, but some slight modifications of this worked as desired.