# Pandas `agg` to list, "AttributeError / ValueError: Function does not reduce"

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Often when we perform `groupby` operations using pandas we may wish to apply several functions across multiple series.

[`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) seems the natural way to perform these groupings and calculations.

However, there seems to be discrepancy between how `groupby.agg` and `groupby.apply` are implemented, because I cannot group to a list using `agg`. Tuple and set works fine, which suggests to me you can only aggregate to immutable types via `agg`. Via `groupby.apply`, I can aggregate one series to a list directly with no issues.

Below is a complete example. Functions (1), (2), (3) complete successfully. (4) comes back with `# ValueError: Function does not reduce`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob', '1/1/18', 'AType', 'blah', 'test', 'test2'],
                   ['Bob', '1/1/18', 'AType', 'blah2', 'test', 'test3'],
                   ['Bob', '1/1/18', 'BType', 'blah', 'test', 'test2']],
                  columns=['NAME', 'DATE', 'TYPE', 'VALUE A', 'VALUE B', 'VALUE C'])


def grouper(df, func):
    f = {'VALUE A': lambda x: func(x), 'VALUE B': 'last', 'VALUE C': 'last'}
    return df.groupby(['NAME', 'DATE', 'TYPE'])['VALUE A', 'VALUE B', 'VALUE C']\
             .agg(f).reset_index()

# (1) SUCCESS
grouper(df, set)

# (2) SUCCESS
grouper(df, tuple)

# (3) SUCCESS
df.groupby(['NAME', 'DATE', 'TYPE', 'VALUE B', 'VALUE C'])['VALUE A']\
  .apply(list).reset_index()

# (4) FAIL
grouper(df, list)

# AttributeError
# ValueError: Function does not reduce
```

Comment: This is exist problem , you can try agg(list) will give back the same , using tuple instead list :-) . grouper(df, tuple)

Comment: @Wen, To clarify, is this (a) a bug, (b) not yet implemented, (c) intentional treatment?

Comment: When pandas with list thing getting messy , cause [1,2,3] will be considered as a series..

Comment: I see, yet you can also assign a tuple to a series, e.g. `df['col'] = (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928415/why-does-df-applytuple-work-but-not-df-applylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much investigation, I have discovered this is a bug, which will be fixed in a future release of pandas.

The offending code in [0.22.x groupby.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.22.x/pandas/core/groupby.py), notice the `isinstance(res, list)`:

```
def _aggregate_series_pure_python(self, obj, func):

    group_index, _, ngroups = self.group_info

    counts = np.zeros(ngroups, dtype=int)
    result = None

    splitter = get_splitter(obj, group_index, ngroups, axis=self.axis)

    for label, group in splitter:
        res = func(group)
        if result is None:
            if (isinstance(res, (Series, Index, np.ndarray)) or
                    isinstance(res, list)):
                raise ValueError('Function does not reduce')
            result = np.empty(ngroups, dtype='O')

        counts[label] = group.shape[0]
        result[label] = res

    result = lib.maybe_convert_objects(result, try_float=0)
    return result, counts
```

[Master branch of groupby.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py), `isinstance(res, list)` omitted:

```
def _aggregate_series_pure_python(self, obj, func):

        group_index, _, ngroups = self.group_info

        counts = np.zeros(ngroups, dtype=int)
        result = None

        splitter = get_splitter(obj, group_index, ngroups, axis=self.axis)

        for label, group in splitter:
            res = func(group)
            if result is None:
                if (isinstance(res, (Series, Index, np.ndarray))):
                    raise ValueError('Function does not reduce')
                result = np.empty(ngroups, dtype='O')

            counts[label] = group.shape[0]
            result[label] = res

        result = lib.maybe_convert_objects(result, try_float=0)
        return result, counts
```